# How do Javascript optimizations compare to C optimizations

Tags: javascript, c, optimization

I'm currently in a low level C class, but I program Javascript as my job.

Here are a couple C optimizations/Problem areas my book has gone over so far (Just started so I don't have much):

- Procedure overhead (restoring registers, creating the stack, etc.)
- Sometimes creating temporary variables instead of reading/writing to memory in loops.

Additionally how much time can be spent 'optimizing' Javascript? C is compiled down to machine code and much more time can be spent on compiling an executable. How much time is spent in a typical JS compiler optimizing?

Javascript is a higher level language than C and because of that I don't actually 'know' what is going on underneath. What optimizations should I worry about? Will what I am learning now in C also apply in Javascript?

Comment: Well, there is no such think as a "typical JS compiler" so .. Chrome/V8 happens to be a very well-optimized JS *implementation*, although FF isn't a dog either. I believe both use *different* approaches, but I have not studied the internals of either. ActionScript is *based on* JavaScript, but can take advantage of static type annotations; dynamic typing is likely the ultimate limitation of JS optimizations (the same "problem" plagues other dynamic languages).

Comment: I think you should look into the actual Javascript engines, at least [V8](http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/data/benchmarks/v5/run.html) and [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey). I would tend to say "no", because there are low-level actions in C that just aren't possible in Javascript (like GC and malloc).

Comment: @JaredFarrish But Java/C# shows that GC vs. malloc can *favor* the GC in a number of use cases. The difference vs. JavaScript is that Java/C# are also strongly-typed ..

Comment: There's also [Native Client in Chromium](https://developers.google.com/native-client/), which offers Pepper C and Pepper C++. That would be a more interesting comparison.

Comment: @pst - The point was "are the techniques I'm learning for C optimization valid in Javascript". The comment is not meant to imply one approach is better or worse than the other, just *different*.

Comment: In addition, [JIT compiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) changes the nature of the game quite a bit, as the JIT compiler as a great deal of information to work with.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher But the JIT can only use what information it has available to it; in a dynamic language much information readily available to a typical static/compiled language is simply *not available* (although some can be recovered through local and even global analysis, which is not trivial). That is, compare the JIT used in the JVM/CLR with the JIT in V8. The V8 JIT has to work more like PyPy/RPython (and try to extract hint information through analysis).

Comment: @pst -- agreed, fully.  I just said it changed the game.  I should have continued and added that `JIT` Javsacript engines and `non-JIT` engines have different optimizations available to them.  For instance, in Chrome, you'll get a huge speed increase if you create an object and its properties in the same order each time. Under older Javascript engines, there would be no different between `var p = {x: 1, y:2}` and `var p = {y:2 , x:1}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript and C have such radically different ways of expressing things that I doubt one could even compare the optimization techniques.

For this post, I'll just look at the optimizations the programmer can make:

**C:**

- Choosing the most appropriate data type.  (int/long/float/double)
- Bit fields and aligning on word boundaries.
- Use of `malloc` and choosing when to free memory and when to reuse it.
- Intermediate calcuations

**Javascript:**

- Avoid creating pointless objects when needed.  Object re-use
- Intermediate calculations
- Avoiding refreshing the DOM too often
- Set big unused references to `null`

Just as a quick example.  The two really are worlds apart, so I'd have to simplify optimization techniques down to:

- Reuse what you can
- Don't make what you don't have to.
- If you do something computationally expensive and you need it again -- save it.
- **Choose an appropriate algorithm.**

The last item on the list is, as far as I am concerned, the most import bit of optimization that any coder can learn how to do.

- Don't use the [BogoSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) if you have a better sort to use.  (Hint, you do.)
- See if your standard library has a fast way of doing what you want to do.  Don't re-invent the wheel until you proved your old wheel doesn't work.
- Don't worry too much about doing micro-optimization until profiling shows you it is worth the effort.

Disclaimer:  Yes, I know the old adage of 'Premature optimization is the root of all evil.'  Choosing a smart, or at the very least, not terribly dumb way to solve a problem is **not** premature..

Comment: What does *Setting big unused references to `null`* refer to exactly?

Comment: If you have a large global array, perhaps it contains some sort of initialization data for making a table, that memory isn't freed as long as there is a reference to that data.  Setting the variable to `null` will allow that value to be freed. Likewise, sometimes large strings can be caught in a closure and setting that variable to `null` will free the space.  On handheld devices, even a few K of RAM can sometimes matter.

Comment: It should be "**Set** big unused references to `null`" then. What you have makes it sound like that's the punitive case.